# Sorting listbox items without loosing track of index in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, sorting, listbox

I have this:
[my Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv8dT.jpg)

And i'm trying to sort the listboxes by ID (listbox1) or type(listbox2) or client (listbox3)

So, I'm trying to sort one of the listbox like this:

```
Public Sub SortListBox(ByVal listBox As ListBox)
Dim TempList1 As New List(Of String)
Dim i As Integer
'For Each LI In listBox.Items
For i = 0 To listBox.Items.Count - 1
    TempList1.Add(listBox.Items(i))
Next
TempList1.Sort()
listBox.DataSource = TempList1
End Sub
```

Then I just call this sub from a laber_click event like this:

```
Private Sub Label25_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label25.Click
    SortListBox(ListBox2)
End Sub
```

The problem is that the other listbox stops making sense becouse the id has changed and the data does not match.

So, my question is: How can I sort this like I would do in excel, expanding the ordered items to the other listboxes?

Hope you can understand.
Thank you!

Comment: Use the same DataSource with a List(of T) and a different `DisplayMember` for each control.  Please read [ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: Wouldn't a multi-columned [**`ListView`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) be better than a `ListBox` for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Using three different listboxes for this kind of operation is not a good way to display all the data you have and it would not be efficient. I would recommend using a `ListView` with multiple columns.

MSDN : [ListView Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx)